# Open gl ES 2 orthographic projection and rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, 2d

my rotation works normally this way :

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0f ,0f, -3f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, i, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
    mTriangle.draw(scratch);
    }
```

with this shader vertex  :

```
      private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
     "}";
```

But when i want to change my 0x;0y coordinate to be at the top left like this :

```
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position =  vec4 ( vPosition.x *  2.0 / 1280.0 - 1.0," +
        "vPosition.y* - 2.0 / 800.0  + 1.0," +
        "vPosition.z, " +
        "1.0);" +
     "}";*
```

With these vertices :

```
     static float triangleCoords[] = {
     300.0f,      0.0f, 0.0f,  
     0.0f,        500.0f, 0.0f,   
     1280.0f,     500.0f, 0.0f    
     };
```

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRQa9.jpg

My triangle appears like i would like but i can't see my rotation anymore . In order to solve i tried a lot of things like multiply this one by uMVPMatrix ,but now i can see the rotation but i always get coordinate problems as it appears at the middle of the screen, and my vertice triangle doesnt fit the size it should :

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH02H.png

My android screen resolution is 1280*800 I would just like to get this triangle with those vertices rotate without being modified this way.
Can someone explain me how to do this .

***EDIT :***
Thanks to  Andon M. Coleman and  SAKrisT , i was able to get my origin point to 0:0 android coordinate at the top left.

if it can help :

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, top, bottom, near, far);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    mTriangle.draw(mProjectionMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: It's bad idea make changes in shader for operations like this. You have matrices for it.

Comment: If i knew how to do this with matrices i will do it , and i will not be there. i did like this cause i found this only solution on stackoverflow after researches. If someone could help me , i mean get a constructiv answer.

Comment: Honestly, your best bet is just to use an orthographic projection matrix where the Y coordinates are flipped. Keep in mind that for anything that uses polygon winding (e.g. face culling) you will have to reverse the direction of the front-face.

Comment: Thanks Andon, could you explain me how i can do it. It seem i'll dont get use of winding direction as i just want to set a 2dimension world.

Comment: @Atypiquenameri Andon, saying right thing. So, revert your shader and try Matrix.orthoM(0, width, height, 0, -1, 10) instead of scratch

Comment: OMFG , thanks you guyz , now it work , don't know if i can give you reputation , anyway you get my gratitude.